# How can I produce summary tables with a grouping value that can potentially appear in more than one column?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the case where a grouping value can appear in two or more columns, is there a best practice for producing summary data?

Please consider the following data:

```
df<-data.frame(Age=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
           Score=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
           Major=c("Art","Art","Art","Math","Math","Science","Science","Science","Science","Science"),
           Major_2=c("Math","Knitting","Math","Science","Science","Knitting","Lava","Knitting","Lava","Knitting"))
```

[image]

I would like to produce a table of summary statistics for people in each major, but each individual (represented by a row in the table) may have more than one major, without any requirement in terms of which of the two major columns houses a given value.

If the majors existed in a single column, I would approach with `dplyr` and produce

```
df_summary<-df%>%
  group_by(Major)%>%
  summarize(Avg_Age=mean(Age),
        Total_Score=sum(Score))
```

[image]

My desired outcome is:

[image]

I can get this result using the code below, but is there a solution that would be easier to read, or perhaps more efficient?

```
##gathering all the possible majors

majors<-unique(c(df$Major,df$Major_2))

##creating a list

answer<-list()

##looping through each major and summarizing

for (maj in majors) {
  answer[[maj]]<-df%>%
    filter(Major==maj |Major_2==maj)%>%
    summarize(Major=maj,
              Avg_Age=mean(Age),
              Total_Score=sum(Score))
  
}

##binding back into the desired table, with a row for each major

awkward_answer<-bind_rows(answer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(Major:Major_2, values_to = "Major") %>%
  group_by(Major) %>%
  summarise(Avg_Age = mean(Age),
            Total_Score = sum(Score))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Major    Avg_Age Total_Score
  <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Art         1              4
2 Knitting    1.75           8
3 Lava        2              2
4 Math        1              5
5 Science     1.71          11
```

Comment: Excellent, and works in practice in my use case where multiple records for an individual exist and unduplicated ID-Major combinations are required.  With an ID column added to this sample data, all I had to do was add `distinct()` in the form: `df%>%
  pivot_longer(Major:Major_2,values_to="Major")%>%
  distinct(ID,Major,.keep_all = TRUE)%>%
  group_by(Major)%>%
  summarise(Avg_Age=mean(Age),
            Total_Score=sum(Score))`